# Fourier transformation of $\log(q^2)/q^4$ in $d=3$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-transform, quantum-field-theory

I currently have the following Fourier transformation that I need to compute
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\log(\mathbf{q^2})}{(\mathbf{q})^4}e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot \mathbf{r}}
\end{equation}
where I know that if I had instead just the $\log(\mathbf{q}^2)$ I would get $-(2\pi r^3)^{-1}$ and for $1/|\mathbf{q}|$ becomes $(2\pi^2 r^2)^{-1}$ and $1/|\mathbf{q}|^2$ would be $(4\pi r^2)^{-1}$. I even know that if I had a $\mathbf{q}^{-4}$ that the Fourier transform would give $-\pi^2 r$ (which would be dependent upon the regularization scheme) but I don't know how to handle the one I first stated. I listed all the previous ones in hope that there may be a way to use them.

Here he how I would start
\begin{align}
\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\log(\mathbf{q}^2)}{\mathbf{q}^4}e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}} & = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^\infty dq\frac{\log(q^2)}{q^4}\cdot q^2\int_{-1}^1 d\cos(\theta) \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi e^{iqr\cos(\theta)}\\
& = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^\infty dq \frac{1}{iqr}{\frac{\log(q^2)}{q^2}}(e^{iqr} - e^{-iqr})\\
\end{align}
and here is where I do not know how to handle the analyticity of the integral. Perhaps I should add a small $i\delta$ into the denominator and then perform the contour integration (where $\delta>0$) which would only include one of the exponential terms (I think). Anyways, any sort of suggestions are helpful, thanks!

Comment: What does $\log \mathbf q$ mean?

Comment: The boldface characters are just $d=3$ vectors, but when I break it down into component form on the RHS it just becomes some value $q^2$. This is why I wanted to put a square on the q's in the logarithm for them to make sense. I made edits to reflect this.

Comment: x-posted on physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/791419/84967

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform can you close this question?

Comment: @MathZilla I can't, but perhaps someone else can. You can also delete it yourself if you want.